# Where is the best place to add an “ssh-add” command in fish shell startup?

Tags: ssh, fish

At some point I added an `ssh-add` invocation to my `config.fish` file. So every time I open a terminal, that runs for a couple of seconds.

Is there a better place to set this, so that it runs upon login? Or do I really do need it to run for every terminal?

Answer (score 3):

To run a command only in a login shell in fish, you can use:

```
if status is-login
  ssh-add
end
```

You can do this either in your `config.fish`, which you are currently using, or you could make things more modular by moving that functionality to something like `~/.config/fish/conf.d/01_ssh-add`, which will automatically be sourced at startup.  The downside is that it *can* make startup more difficult to debug, if you forget to check `conf.d`. Once you get used to it, though, I think conf.d is far more idiomatic in fish.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it conditional. Use `ssh-add -l` to list added keys. If anything is added, it will exit with `0` code, otherwise with `1`. I'm not familiar with fish's syntax, but in bash-like shells you could use something like this:

```
ssh-add -l > /dev/null || ssh-add
```